# Remove contents of element but preserve same children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have:

```
<li class="parent">
  <a href="#">Text I WANT to remove</a>
  <ul>
    <li class="child">
      <a href="#">Text I DO NOT WANT to remove</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

How do I remove text from the parent's `a` element but not any of the childrens'?

EDIT: removed extra closing `a` tag for clarity.

Comment: It's not really a parent <a> element because your code is invalid.
Your <a> tag closes before the <ul> starts, and there is another </a> after the <ul>.

Comment: Um... just do it. Or show us what you tried and we can help you identify what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the  `$("#element").text()`  function.

Just set it to an empty string :

```
$(".parent > a").text('');
```

I am using the `>` part of the selector to state that I want to use only the `<a>` tags that are direct children - that means they appear in the first level.

> Reference : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

Comment: I always forget about that selector! Threw that in and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: This is the easiest way, and what makes the difference here is the class refernce, tho if you have an element with specific material to dynamically remove, I'd really suggest giving the element and ID and using that ID to reach the element, even if you put the ID on the li and use his `>` strat, it would be better in that classes are often better used for css  so that they can be used repitivly whereas an ID is ment to be on one element.

Comment: @SpYk3HH -You are very correct, it all depends on the context and how you are planning to use it. Jared - you are very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the following. This will remove all html elements inside a.

```
$(".parent a:first").html("");
```

Comment: Just to be clear. I'm not the *downvoter* but the OP is asking just to remove text wrapped within an element and not the element itself (along with its children).

Comment: **It would work** - however If the tag were to contain other elements other than plain text they would be removed as well.

Comment: well in that case you can use .text() instead of html

Answer (score 1):

First, your HTML is invalid.  You have an extra closing anchor tag

Then you can do something like $(".parent a:first_child")

Check this out for more info:
http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/

Comment: This is just hand-typed pseudo code, my real code is nothing like this.